# Connecting and charging 2 gopro cameras to a raspberry pi further away than 3 meters

Tags: power, usb, raspberry-pi, camera

I want to connect 2 gopro cameras via usb to a raspberry pi, and charge them as well.

Because the raspberry pi can't provide enough current via its usb ports, I'm injecting 12v from the same power supply the raspberry pi draws 5v from (it's a mini-atx power supply).

On the cameras side, I have a step down regulator from 12v to 5v for the cameras.
There's also a usb hub IC, because the cameras are further away than 3 meters, and as I understand, usb connections don't work well further than 2-3 meters.

I'm injecting 12v to the V+ and V- lines of the usb cable. Closer to the camera, the step down regulator brings it down to 5v.

The D+ and D- usb lines go directly to the usb hub chip, at the same distance where the regulator is. The regulator outputs its 5v to the usb hub.
All 4 lines (V+, V-, D+, D-) connect to the usb-c cable that plugs to the camera.

I'm encountering some issues that are becoming very hard to understand why they are happening.

The cameras will charge sometimes, and sometimes they won't.
The usb connection to the cameras will work sometimes, and others it won't.

This is what comes up on the raspberry pi when everything is detected via the `lsusb` command:

```
Bus 001 Device 037: ID 2672:0056 GoPro HERO10 Black
Bus 001 Device 036: ID 214b:7250 Huasheng Electronics USB2.0 HUB
Bus 001 Device 031: ID 2672:0056 GoPro HERO10 Black
Bus 001 Device 030: ID 214b:7250 Huasheng Electronics USB2.0 HUB
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

This is what comes up with `dmesg`:

```
[Tue Jul  4 14:56:25 2023] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=214b, idProduct=7250, bcdDevice= 1.00
[Tue Jul  4 14:56:25 2023] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[Tue Jul  4 14:56:25 2023] usb 1-1.1: Product: USB2.0 HUB
[Tue Jul  4 14:56:25 2023] hub 1-1.1:1.0: USB hub found
[Tue Jul  4 14:56:25 2023] hub 1-1.1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[Tue Jul  4 14:56:25 2023] usb 1-1.1.2: new high-speed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd
[Tue Jul  4 14:56:25 2023] usb 1-1.1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=2672, idProduct=0056, bcdDevice= 0.01
[Tue Jul  4 14:56:25 2023] usb 1-1.1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[Tue Jul  4 14:56:25 2023] usb 1-1.1.2: Product: HERO10 Black
[Tue Jul  4 14:56:25 2023] usb 1-1.1.2: Manufacturer: GoPro
[Tue Jul  4 14:56:25 2023] usb 1-1.1.2: SerialNumber: C3461326555015
[Tue Jul  4 14:56:25 2023] cdc_ncm 1-1.1.2:1.0: MAC-Address: 24:74:f7:cb:92:2f
[Tue Jul  4 14:56:25 2023] cdc_ncm 1-1.1.2:1.0 eth1: register 'cdc_ncm' at usb-0000:01:00.0-1.1.2, CDC NCM, 24:74:f7:cb:92:2f
[Tue Jul  4 14:56:25 2023] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Anything I can look into?
Thank you very much in advance.

Cheers